# Tensorflow adding op referencing some functions

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to add some operations in tensorflow. However there are some problems when I make the function.

In my function, there exists function which is exists in core/kernels/training_op_helpers.h.

Bazel said that it needs dependency, so I added to bazel BUILD file, however there is error, which is that it has illegal dependency.

I found that there are some disallowed dependency in tf_custom_op_library in tensorflow.bzl. Is there any special reason for that?

However is there any way to using some funciton in tensorflow functions? I think that there is some limitation to use the function when I add the op in tensorflow.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

your bazel project of the custom ops must be in the same workspace with the dependent files. And load the tensorflow .bzl in your BUILD file.